# Visual Studio Forms Designer and the size of invisible objects

Tags: visual-studio, forms, designer

The form designer in Visual Studio is giving me fits and I'm hoping someone can at least point out what's going on.

The latest incarnation involved a tab sheet with some controls on each of the sheets.  Sheets #2 and #3 were done and I was working on #1--when suddenly two controls on sheet #2 vanished in the running program.  Some hunting showed that they had their width set to zero--yet they are fine in the designer.

The common factor I have had (I have had other such disappearances) is that the components are invisible when the form is created.

For any given state of the program the behavior is completely consistent but when other controls are created or destroyed the behavior may change.

Comment: Windows Forms designer or Web Forms designer?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Visual Studio's [Document Outline Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w.aspx)? It's very useful for visualisation when dealing with complex layouts.

Comment: The layout isn't that complex and it's correct in the designer--the offending controls are there.  When it's run one dimension is zeroed and it vanishes.